# AWS unable to reach RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, vpc

I have a AWS RDS instance (PSQL), which is public accessible. For testing I attached a Security group that has on port 5432 all access 0.0.0.0/0. My VPC has a Internet Gateway attached and has the following

```
192.168.0.0/16  local   

0.0.0.0/0 igw-0f41c33417cbccb8c
```

If I try to connect to the instance I get a network timeout and it seems my request is blocked.
But I dont find anything else that should block the connection

If it helps the VPC and the subnets are default and created for `eksctl` the major adaption I made was attaching a Internet Gateway

From inside the VPC I can access the RDS instance from outside (eg my local machine I can't)

Comment: Is your RDS subnet properly set the routing table to access the internet gateway? Or is your subnet private? Then NAT gateway is needed.

Comment: The subnets of the have the following Route table associations: ```192.168.0.0/16
local and
0.0.0.0/0
igw-0f41c33417cbccb8c``` the inbound rules are ```100
ALL Traffic
ALL
ALL
0.0.0.0/0
ALLOW
*
ALL Traffic
ALL
ALL
0.0.0.0/0
DENY```

Comment: the attached igw `igw-0f41c33417cbccb8c` is the internet gateway

Comment: Are you trying to connect from inside, or outside of the VPC?

Comment: From inside the cluster I can connect from outside not

Comment: Seems like Your RDS is in private subnet, so publicly accessible will no effect

Comment: @Adiii I have per Availability zone two subnets. one on 0.0.0.0/0 attached with a NAT and one with 0.0.0.0/0 attached with a IGW

Comment: Then did you check the security group

Comment: Which seems it was the problem. I attached to both subnets a IGW instead of one with a NAT and one with IGW. Now I can access from inside and outside

Comment: okay so now it perfect